# Assign Ajax response to php variable

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-5.1

How do I assign my ajax response to a php variable, if it is even possible?

In my Laravel controller I have this method for that purpose:

```
public function editProductPost(Request $request)
{
    return response()->json([
        'sliderValue' => $request->get('value')
    ]);
}
```

And this is my Ajax:

```
    /**
     * Ajax Post
     */
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });

    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        contentType: "application/json",
        url: "{{ Route('editProductPost', $product->id) }}",
        headers: {
            'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
        },
        data: JSON.stringify({ 
            value: getSliderVal,
            productId : getPrId
        }),
        datatype: 'json',
        success: function(response) {
            // get response
            console.log(response.sliderValue)
        }
```

Comment: What are you talking about? Ajax to php? Sorry, don't understand anything ...

Comment: @eisbehr I get the ajax response right, I want to create a php variable which holds that value on each ajax call

Comment: I'm pretty sure you don't understand what `client-side` and `server-side` means?! JavaScript runs in the browser and php on your server. You can't set a php variable inside js ... What you can do is to extend your `editProductPost` and do some other work there.

Comment: You cant assign the Ajax response to a PHP variable

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to do something like this:

```
public function editProductPost(Request $request)
{
    // Create your JSON response
    $response = response()->json([
        'sliderValue' => $request->get('value')
    ]);

    // Assign the content of the response to a variable
    $responseContent = $response->content();

    // Return your response
    return $response;
}
```

Comment: How would you call this in the view?

Comment: What do you mean? I think you're misunderstanding the difference between server-side code (PHP/Laravel) and client-side code (HTML/Javascript/CSS). What are you trying to achieve exactly?

Comment: I want to use that variable in a php loop in my view like for($i = 0; $i < $reponse; $i++)...

Comment: If you want to do that, then AJAX isn't the way to go. At the point of making the AJAX request, PHP has already run and rendered the view. You *could* use the variable returned in the AJAX call in a Javascript for loop to do something. Like this `function(response) { for (var i=0; i < response.sliderValue; i++) {
  /*Do something*/
} }`